# Attach external system terminal into Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I have been running into a trouble whereby Spyder IPython console is not producing Matplotlib figures as desired. I thought initially that there is something wrong in my code since jupyter notebook gives me the same wrong figures. However, when running the script in Spyder using external terminal the figures are produced as desired. Also, when I run the code in VSC the correct figures are displayed.

So the only option I am left with in Spyder is to use the external terminal to execute the code. However, it is quite a pain every time to run some codes and then manually close the terminal.

I would like to know if there is a way to permanently attach the external terminal inside Spyder? I hate the IPython console when it comes to plotting matplotlib figures!!

Comment: Have you tried integrating Jupyter Notebooks with Spyder? I belive they might make the visualization life easier instead of using the Ipython console. There is a cool plugin here: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-notebook

Comment: @PedroTorres Thanks  for your advice, I am aware of this plugin. The whole problem is IPython when it comes to plotting matplotlib figures, and hence jupyter notebook basically uses IPython there wont be any difference than the IPython in spyder itself!. appreciations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Sorry but there's no way to dock an external Python terminal inside Spyder.

Comment: Is there other console I can use instead of IPython?

Comment: No, there isn't. However, it'd be better if you could open an issue in our [issues tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues) and let us know exactly what's your problem with Matplotlib.